# How do I reference inserted row in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet, Names, populated by a google form. In another sheet, copiedNames, I am referencing Names column B starting from row 100 `='Names'!B100:B` and have drop filled this formula into the all the cells below. The row numbers in copiedNames are not the same as the row numbers in Names.

When a new google form entry is input into Names, the formula in copiedNames break.  I understand that this is because new rows are being inserted into Names and copiedNames is referencing rows *after* the inserted rows. How do I reference the inserted rows so that I can keep referencing the new names as they come in?

I've seen suggestions to try arrayformula, index, indirect, but I can't figure out something that works.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked to use `=Arrayformula('Names'!B100:B)` in a single cell and *not* drop fill the cells underneath.